# While selecting data from database using following code

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have used this code to select data from table tbl_users but it is showing 1. what does it mean..

```
 require_once('config.php');
 $dbCon = getConnection();


 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
 $stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);


 print($stmt->execute());
```

can Anyone Help...????

Comment: it means your query run successfully.

Comment: here the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Comment: What help you need. What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: [You have to use either foreach or fetch() to get your data from the statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#foreach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the query runs successfully, `$stmt->execute()` returns `true`, which will print as `1`.

---

To return data:

```
//Returns first row as array
$row = $stmt->fetch();

//Returns first row as key => value array
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Returns all rows as key=>value arrays
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can use this to print data like so:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//Print all data
$print_r($rows);

//Print data row-by-row
foreach($rows as $row){
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: For the false it is not true.

Answer (score 0):

At this moment you're printing the response of the query, not the results.

To print the results you should do something like this:

```
foreach ($stmt as $row) {
        print $row['name'] . "\t";
        print $row['first_name'] . "\t";
        print $row['birth_date'] . "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On successful execution of `query` `execute()` return `True` .

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_users";
$stmt = $dbCon->prepare($sql);

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```